# Is correct this delete operation from a dynamic array? How to fix memory?

Tags: arrays, c, string, dynamic-arrays

I have a dynamic array of strings, for example "123", "231" etc.
Next I need to delete a particular array string. For the deletion I used the normal technique used for static arrays, that is to move all the elements to the left by one position, in order to overwrite the deleted element. But since the array is dynamic, how do I fix the memory? That is, to decrement the memory this array is using? Here is my code:
**PART OF CODE TO INSERT A STRING:**

```
char **received_messages;

if(array_size == 0){
    debug_level == 2 && printf("First message received..\n");
    received_messages = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    received_messages[0] = malloc((1024+1) * sizeof(char));
    array_size = array_size + 1;
    strcpy(received_messages[0],id);
}
else{

for(int i=0; i<array_size; i++){
    debug_level == 2 && printf("Compare between %s and %s\n", received_messages[i],id);
    if( (strcmp(received_messages[i],id)) == 0){
        id_found= 1;
    }
}

if(id_found== 1){
    debug_level == 2 && printf("ID found.\n");
}else{
    debug_level == 2 && printf("ID not found.\n");
    received_messages[array_size] = malloc((1024+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(received_messages[array_size],id);
    array_size = array_size + 1;
}

}
```

**PART OF CODE TO DELETE A STRING:**

```
    for(int j=0; j<array_size;j++){
        printf("I'm searching the SN to delete. Compare %s to %s\n", received_messages[j], id_to_delete);
        if(strstr(received_messages[j], id_to_delete) != NULL){
        printf("Sequence number found. It is %s\n", id_to_delete);
        for(int k=j; k<array_size; k++){
            received_messages[k] = received_messages[k+1];
            array_size = array_size -1;
        }
    } 
    }
    printf("Now, the array has %d elements. Actually valid sequence number are: \n", array_size);
    if(array_size > 0){
    for(int j=0; j<array_size; j++){
        printf("%d) %s\n", j+1, received_messages[j]);
    }
    }else{
        printf("Actually no valid sequence number.\n");
    }
```

Comment: When you delete an element, you never `free` the memory have allocated for it.

Comment: You also have a much worse problem than the memory leak from not freeing memory: You never reallocate the array `received_messages` itself when you increase its size. That means for any index except `0` you will go out of bounds and have 
*undefined behavior*.

Comment: Unfortunately I know, in fact I would like to know how to do it. I don't know how to free up the memory for the item that was deleted.

Comment: If you don't need the strings to be stored in contiguous memory and you're looking at adding or removing a lot of strings, may I suggest that you use a linked list? That way it would ease your memory allocation/deallocation as you add and remove strings from the list.

Comment: Before moving the contents of the `received_messages` array, call `free(received_messages[j])`

Answer (score 1):

For starters this code snippet is incorrect if the memory for the array pointed to by the pointer `received_messages` was not reallocated

```
}else{
    debug_level == 2 && printf("ID not found.\n");
    received_messages[array_size] = malloc((1024+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(received_messages[array_size],id);
    array_size = array_size + 1;
}
```

If previously there were allocated `array_size` elements then using the index `array_size` results in accessing memory beyond the allocated array.

In this code snippet

```
for(int j=0; j<array_size;j++){
    printf("I'm searching the SN to delete. Compare %s to %s\n", received_messages[j], id_to_delete);
    if(strstr(received_messages[j], id_to_delete) != NULL){
    printf("Sequence number found. It is %s\n", id_to_delete);
    for(int k=j; k<array_size; k++){
        received_messages[k] = received_messages[k+1];
        array_size = array_size -1;
    }
}
```

it is unclear why you are using the function `strstr` instead of the function `strcmp`.

The inner for loop

```
    for(int k=j; k<array_size; k++){
        received_messages[k] = received_messages[k+1];
        array_size = array_size -1;
    }
```

has to be moved from the outer for loop. Moreover this statement

```
array_size = array_size -1;
```

has to be moved from this inner loop. Within the loop it does not make a sense because for each iteration of the loop the variable `array_size` is decremented.

This statement

```
received_messages[k] = received_messages[k+1];
```

invokes undefined behavior due to the index expression `k + 1` when k is equal to `array_size - 1` because in this case the index expression is equal to `array_size` that is not a valid index for the array containing `array_size` elements.

Instead of the loop you could use the function `memmove` and then the function `realloc` to decrease the allocated memory due to removing an element from the array.